# attempt to change value in object in nested loop in react but i have issue

Tags: reactjs, jsx, nested-loops, map-function

I have an issue with react that I have an object of questions holds [{question, correctAnswer, options : [{id, answer, isSelected: false}]}] I'm trying to change isSelected value to true when the user selects the answer with the map function but it returns an array of options only not the whole objects how can I do that?

here is the main object :

[image: Main Object content]

here is my code :

```
    function selectAnswers(id) {
        setQestions(prevQuestions => {
          return prevQuestions.map(question => {
            return question.options.map(answer => {
              return answer.id === id
                ? { ...answer, isSelected: !answer.isSelected }
                : answer;
            });
          });
        });
  }
```

the result without the rest of an object :

[image: Sample of input]

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer, you need to do something like this:**
(I corrected your `Qestions` typo)

```
function selectAnswers(id) {
  setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
    return prevQuestions.map((question) => {
      let newQuestion = question;

      question.options.forEach((option, index) => {
        if (option.id === id) {
          const newOption = { ...option, isSelected: !option.isSelected };
          const newOptions = question.options.slice();
          newOptions.splice(index, 1, newOption);
          newQuestion = {
            ...newQuestion,
            options: newOptions,
          };
        }
      });

      return newQuestion;
    });
  });
}
```

**Long answer: Let's examine your code**

```
function selectAnswers(id) {
  setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
    return prevQuestions.map((question) => {
      return question.options.map((answer) => {
        return answer.id === id
          ? { ...answer, isSelected: !answer.isSelected }
          : answer;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Your `setQuestions` callback should return a new array of `question`. It is returning an array, let's see what that array contains.

```
prevQuestions.map((question) => {
  return question.options.map((answer) => {
    return answer.id === id
      ? { ...answer, isSelected: !answer.isSelected }
      : answer;
  });
});
```

The callback passed to `prevQuestions.map` doesn't return a `question` object. Instead, it is returning an array of of `option`s (or `answer`s – to avoid confusion I suggest you just name your variable `option`). This is what causes the bug.

Comment: thanks for your support but according to your code after selecting the answer it returned the question object with one selected option without the rest of the options.

Comment: @ahmedhussin sorry for that, I corrected the answer I ran some tests to make sure it works. Let me know if there's any problem